# G.add_edge error in Networkx as key error

Tags: python, graph, networkx, keyerror

I tried to add edges from a list:

```
for first in G.nodes():
    G_dict = copy.copy(G.node[first])
    sorted_G = sorted(G_dict.iteritems(), key = op.itemgetter(1), reverse = True)
        for number in range(0, close_limit):
           edge_temp.append((first,sorted_G[number][0]))
           print(edge_temp)
           G.add_edges_from(edge_temp)
```

When I printed the edge_temp, it worked very well. However, when I tried to use the function `G.add_edges_from()`, the error was:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Wireless\rd_pc_contact1.py", line 95, in <module>
    G.add_edges_from(edge_temp)
     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\networkx-  
     1.8.1py2.7.egg\networkx\classes\graph.py", line 785, in add_edges_from
     datadict=self.adj[u].get(v,{})
  KeyError: 0
```

I can not understand the reason why error occurred. Could you clearly explain the error?

Comment: I've tried to correct the indentation on your code. Feel free to fix if needed.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like one of the edges you are looking for doesn't exist.
hard to tell without data.

you probably want to just iterate number through sorted_G rather than with an explicit list. but maybe you have a reason for doing that.

Answer (score 0):

From the posted code, it's hard to tell what's in `edge_temp`. It's a list that you are appending to each time. Odds are you only want the edge `(first,sorted_G[number][0])` added *once*, but you are doing it many times each loop. I'd suggest changing the `add_edges_from` line to:

```
G.add_edges_from([(first,sorted_G[number][0])])
```